# How to muxing a HEVC Annex B raw video file into a TS containter without changing its start code with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, containers, encode, codec

I researched for a while and had read [Multiplex a HEVC-Video into a MPEG-Transportstream with FFMPEG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40109358/multiplex-a-hevc-video-into-a-mpeg-transportstream-with-ffmpeg) and [Convert H.264 Annex B to MPEG-TS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24025944/convert-h-264-annex-b-to-mpeg-ts)
but non of these answer my question.
 I tried `ffmpeg -y -f hevc -i out.h265   -c copy -f mpegts output1.ts`
but it got 2 errors:

**[mpegts @ 00000230d3bad2c0]** Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0. This is deprecated and will stop working in the future. Fix your code to set the timestamps properly.

**[mpegts @ 00000230d3bad2c0]** first pts value must be set
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid data found when processing input

How can i wrap a HEVC Annex B into .ts file without changing its start code?.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try the two step method in the first link?

Comment: yes.But it's not annex raw with start code anymore

Comment: the first step when you wrap annex b into mp4.It's not annex b anymore

Comment: Naturally, MP4 requires length-prefixed stream. startcodes are added again when remuxed to TS. First step is required to generate timestamps.

Comment: So after the second step,It's still Annex B in .ts container?

Comment: After 2nd step, it gets reformatted as Annex B